# Laravel Migrations - General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

I have multiple tables with multiple foreign keys, but when I migrate it can not find the other migration yet because it is not made yet.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `post` add constraint `post_vote_id_foreign` foreign key (`vote_id`) references `vote` (`id`))
```

Post table

```
    Schema::create('post', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('topic_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('vote_id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('summary');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('topic_id')->references('id')->on('topic');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('vote_id')->references('id')->on('vote');

    });
```

Vote table to see all the votes for the post

```
        Schema::create('vote', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('post');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

        });
```

Comment: These migrations will always return this error. You have a circular reference `post` table has a column `vote_id` which references `vote` table and `vote` table has a column `post_id` which references `post` table - so whichever migration runs first will error out. Think over your migrations design/definition again why would you need such circular reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's not good to have circular references - most probably indicates bad design. However if you really want to have the circular reference

```php
Schema::create('post', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('topic_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('vote_id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('summary');
    $table->string('image');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('topic_id')->references('id')->on('topic');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

You can alter the post table to define the foreign key after the vote table has been created

```php
Schema::create('vote', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('post');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

});

Schema::table('post', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('vote_id')->references('id')->on('vote');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its important to note that migration files run in order of creation. So go through your table design and get those independent ones first(change their file name i.e timestamp so they come first), then followed by the dependent(ones that have the foreign keys to the independents). I hope you understand?

Comment: I have tried that, but those 2 tables need each other so I cant really change the name to fix that problem

Comment: No i think you got me wrong. When i said "change name", i meant the filename NOT table name. You change the filename of the migration files so that the less dependent migration files (tables) will be created first before those ones with foreign keys, else you will keep getting the error you are having.

Comment: And remove vote_id from post table. You really dont need it and that is what is causing the error. PS: post_migration file should come before vote_migration file.

Answer (score 0):

For googlers ... in my case it was because the parent table was myIsam type and not innodb